# How to smooth a modal in blender 2.82

Tags: modeling, interface, eevee-render-engine

I am switching into the new blender 2.82 with the new layout and I cannot find out where the smooth option is please help me find the smooth option in the new blender layout. 
if this is a duplicate question sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be in **Object Mode** and then either right-click on the mesh or expand the **Object** menu and select **Shade Smooth**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!